# Generator expression evaluation with several ... for ... in ... parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, nested, generator

**Question**: What does Python do under the hood when it sees this kind of expression?

```
sum(sum(i) for j in arr for i in j)
```

---

**My thoughts**: *The above expression works.* But as it is written in [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> generator expressions are implemented using a function scope

Not to be verbose :) I have an array with the following layout (*as an example*):

```
>>> arr = [
           [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],
           [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
          ]
```

At first, I try to sum all elements of `arr` with the following expression:

```
>>> sum(sum(i) for i in j for j in arr)
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

It raises `NameError`, but why not `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment` if it is implemented using a function scope, what is evaluation rules for `for ... in ...` from left-to-right or from right-to-left? And what is an equivalent generator function for this generator expression?

---

**EDIT**:

I catch the idea. Thanks @vaultah for some insight. In this case `j` is the argument that is send to generator expression:

```
>>> sum(sum(i) for i in j for j in arr)  # NameError
```

that's why I get this weird `NameError`.

---

[@Eric answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552690/6793085) shows that generator expression:

```
>>> sum(sum(i) for j in arr for i in j)
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> def __gen(arr):
        for j in arr:
            for i in j:
                yield sum(i)

>>> sum(__gen(arr))
```

---

Comment: Is your question about "why do I get this error instead of a different error"?  it seems you want to accomplish something like `sum(item for grid in arr for row in grid for item in row)`.  but I take it that isn't what you are actually asking about.

Comment: You seem to have a whole bunch of different questions here - the list comprehension at the top of your question is not the same as the ones elsewhere - is this deliberate?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes it is, I like your solution!!!

Comment: @Eric there is only one question, about generator expression: `sum(sum(i) for j in arr for i in j)` how it works? In **my thoughts**, I only try to explain, what steps I did to achieve right answer, so I realized that I do not understand what's going on. Also I like [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39552690/6793085) and have no idea why it is downvoted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it is a generator or a list comprehension, the comprehension nesting is the same. It is easier to see what is going on with a list comprehension and that is what I will use in the examples below.

Given:

```
>>> arr
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

You can flatten the List of Lists of Ints by 1 level using a nested list comprehension (or generator):

```
>>> [e for sl in arr for e in sl]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

You can flatten completely, given that structure, by nesting again (example only; there are better ways to flatten a deeply nested list):

```
>>> [e2 for sl2 in [e for sl in arr for e in sl] for e2 in sl2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Since `sum` takes an iterable, the second flattening is not necessary in your example:

```
>>> [sum(e) for sl in arr for e in sl]
[6, 15, 24, 33]   # sum of those is 78...
```

---

The general form of a comprehension is:

```
[ expression      for a_variable in a_DEFINED_sequence     optional_predicate ]
```

You can get the same `NameError` you are seeing on your nested comprehension by using a non defined name:

```
>>> [c for c in not_defined]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'not_defined' is not defined
```

So the error you see on `sum(sum(i) for i in j for j in arr)` is because `j` has not been defined yet. Comprehensions are evaluated left to right, inner to outer. The definition of `j` as a sequence is to the right of its attempted use.

To unroll the list comprehension into nested loops, the *inner* (or left hand) section becomes the *outer* loop:

```
for sl in arr:
    for sl2 in sl:
        for e in sl2:
           # now you have each int in the LoLoInts...
           # you could use yield e for a generator here
```

---

Your final question: Why do you get a `TypeError` with `gen = (j for j in arr)`?

That generator expression does nothing. Example:

```
>>> [j for j in arr]
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
>>> [j for j in arr] == arr
True
```

So the expression `(j for j in arr)` just returns a generator over `arr`.

And `sum` does not know how to add that or arr either:

```
>>> sum(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Since `gen` in your example is returning the same data structure, that is your error.

To fix it:

```
>>> gen=(e for sl in arr for e in sl)
>>> sum(sum(li) for li in gen)
78
```

Comment: Thank you! You wrote: *"The order of the elements in a nested list comprehension (or generator) just is the syntax of nesting; the inner element is the element with higher priority."* What does it mean - higher priority? As I see it, the inner element is the element that is iterated most slowly (and actually it is an argument that is passed to genexp).

Comment: I suppose by *higher priority* I meant the first to be encountered and parsed. I will clarify in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

> What does Python do under the hood when it sees this kind of expression?
>
> ```
>  sum(sum(i) for j in array for i in j)
> ```

It becomes something equivalent to:

```
def __gen(it):
    # "it" is actually in locals() as ".0"
    for j in it:
        for i in j:
            yield sum(i)
sum(__gen(iter(arr)))
```

Note that both `__iter__` and the name resolution happen outside the function scope. This only applies to the first `for` loop

[PEP 0289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details) explains this in more detail

Comment: I think `sum(__gen( arr ))` without explicit call for iterator will be enough.

Comment: @godaygo; Yes, but that would be wrong. Try `g = (x for x in 1)`. That wouldn't throw an error if `iter` were inside the generator